# Coronavirus mutation: bad luck or a consequence of vaccination?

Tags: virology, mutations, coronavirus

I would like to know whether a mutation within a virus (such as the new coronavirus mutation that appeared in England [source](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2020/12/mutant-coronavirus-united-kingdom-sets-alarms-its-importance-remains-unclear)) is a consequence of the vaccination program - maybe because it is stimulated to “fight against the vaccine”? Or whether it is just bad luck and the virus just happened to mutate during this vaccination time?

Additionally, if there any other historical evidence, can you cite examples?

Comment: A few (slightly pedantic points). The 'mutation' would never be a result of the vaccination program - mutation happen quasi-randomly. What you are suggesting is that the vaccination may cause **selection** on the mutation which may drive it to high frequency. Secondly, the virus doesn't 'fight against the vaccine'. The vaccine stimulates an immune response which causes the human body to more effectively fight the virus.

Comment: What vaccination programme? Almost nobody in Britain has been vaccinated yet! Or do you think the viruses heard about it on Twitter? Please do some homework before you post.

Comment: @user438383 thank you for your feedback. I sure did not know about this. Good to know the historical question has some relevance :D

Comment: @David I’m sorry if my OP offended you somehow. I did not know being curious would cause such a harm. And my supposition is that, even though the vaccination program just started, it is a coincidence like Chris mentioned. And if you believe there is no vaccination program yet... all good :)

Comment: I am not offended by your question, just trying to weed out questions that do not conform to our remit or standards. And I actually live in the country at issue and am aware of the state of our vaccination programme, whereas, you, from your US spelling, presumably are not and do not. As someone in the relatively high category 3, I still await my turn for the vaccine which there is every reason to believe  will be as effective against this strain as the one against which it was developed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is simply a coincidence. A RNA Virus will mutate all the time (although this one is pretty stable), there are thousands of known mutations (see [Nextstrain](https://nextstrain.org/sars-cov-2/) for detailed information).

[image]

It is only a matter of time, until one of these will dominate the others. It may also be the effect of a few superspreading events where one virus type is strongly promoted, although it bears no or only a little effect over the other virus strains. Time and research will tell.

However, it is pretty much unlikely that one mutation in the spike protein (or even a few ones) will render the vaccine useless. The reason is twofold: First, the whole spike protein has a size between 180 and 200 kDa ([source](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41401-020-0485-4)) meaning the protein has a lot of different epitopes against which antibodies can be directed. To render the vaccine useless, the whole protein had to be different.

This brings us to the second problem, because the spike protein is the protein which interacts with the target cell. If it would completely be changed, the virus would need a different receptor to interact with in order to enter the cell. Highly unlikely to happen, as the virus would need to "re-invent" it path of entry. As far as I know this has never been observed before.

Comment: Nobody has been vaccinated here yet! A few high-risk last week. Please do not accept invalid premises in bad questions.

Answer (score 3):

As it has been pointed in the comments by @user438383, the mutation itself cannot be a consequence of the vaccination program - what is really suggested is that this is an *escape mutation*, i.e., adaptation that makes the virus viable in vaccinated persons.

However, there is no evidence (yet) that the new strain affects those who have been vaccinated - it well may be that these people are equally protected against this new strain. Moreover, chronologically the new mutation likely preceeds the vaccination campaign that has began only recently (even if it was detected/reported just after the beginning of the campaign).

Comment: Nobody has been vaccinated yet! A few high-risk last week. Please do not accept invalid premises in bad questions.

Comment: @David you seem to be misinformed. As of 3 days ago, 350,000 people in the UK have been vaccinated.

Comment: …out of a population of?